# Stripe PaymentElement only shows card for subscriptions

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm following the docs to set up subscriptions with the new PaymentElement here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements#display-payment-method

I'm creating the subscription with multiple payment methods like so:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: data.user_id,
            items: [{
                price: 'price_1JUJCuK8vJwr3oKEoGrsdcIn',
            }],
            payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
            expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
            payment_settings: {
      payment_method_types: ['card', 'sepa_debit', 'klarna', 'ach_credit_transfer', 'paper_check'],
    },
        });
```

However, the payment element only shows card and no other options, is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only see the card payment method, then there are two possible reasons as [explained here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment-methods-setting):

1. You forgot to activate the corresponding payment methods in your [account settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payments).
2. There might be restrictions that prevent some payment methods from being used. For example Klarna is not available for subscriptions, so it won’t be displayed in the PaymentElement. You can find which payment methods are available for subscriptions [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options#payment-method-product-support).

If that doesn’t solve the issue, then maybe something is wrong with your frontend code or with how the PaymentIntent is sent to the PaymentElement. In that case, please share more code of your Stripe integration.

Comment: Some payment methods are only available with certain currencies so that is also worth checking.